# Date comparison in PIVOT table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have a query with PIVOT table, like,

```
SELECT * 
   FROM (SELECT ID, ID,Date FROM Table1) AS P 
PIVOT 
    (   
      COUNT (P.ID)
      FOR P.Date in ([08/17/2006],[08/18/2006])  -- [MM/DD/YYYY] - Format
    ) as pvt
```

In above query, `P.Date` is `datetime2(7)` so, I am getting the data like,

```
P.Date = '2006-08-17 15:30:23.0000000'
```

But i am comparing with `'2006-08-17'`. Here date part is same, even though I am not getting the results.

My aim is to display the count of the ID when the date matches.

I have tried with `Convert()`, But it is not allowing at `PIVOT` table in `FOR` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the `CAST()` in the inner select:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
  SELECT ID, ID, Cast(yourDateValue as Date) newdate  -- perform the conversion here
  FROM Table1 
) AS P 
PIVOT 
(   
  COUNT (P.ID)
  FOR newdate in ([08/17/2006], [08/18/2006])  -- [MM/DD/YYYY] - Format
) as pvt
```